# Difference between limit number of connections setting in IIS and the Max Pool Size

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, iis-7, asp.net, asp

I am trying to understand the difference between the "Max Pool Size" setting in the connection-string against the Limit setting in the IIS server manager...whether they are referring to the same thing? if not what does each do?

To make it clear, I attached a code snipped for the connection-string statement and a photo for the "Limit" setting in the IIS manager.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="TrackingConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=100;Pooling=true;
        Initial Catalog=Tracking;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Attached is a photo of the "Limit" setting in ISS manager.

[image: Limit Setting in ISS manager]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they are not the same thing.

- The `Max Pool Size` parameter affects the database server connection pooling between the webserver and the database; in case of `TrackingConnectionString`, the [Tracking Database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee236906(v=bts.10).aspx).
- The *Limit number of connections* on the IIS website configuration [limits](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh831681.aspx#Edit_Limits) the number of connections allowed to a website, i.e. connections between clients and the web server.

  > The value must be an integer between `0` and `4294967295` (unlimited).
  >   Setting the number to be unlimited circumvents constant administration
  >   if your connections tend to fluctuate. However, system performance can
  >   be negatively affected if the number of connections exceeds your
  >   system resources. Restricting a website to a specified number of
  >   connections can keep performance stable.

Comment: now it is all clear.